# How can I cancel lock picking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

If I accidentally click the lock pick/steal icon, is there a way to cancel it? Clicking it again or hitting the key associated with stealing does nothing. I’m just stuck with a message on my screen saying, “Select target for pilfering...” forever. If I click on something that isn’t a person or a locked door, the message remains.

I just stole a shopping list from some poor soul, but I don’t want to risk attracting the attention of the guards every time I accidentally click on that icon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! Click the right mouse button while the text is up and it will cancel the action to steal.